# Trying to create a lua ghub macro for offline usage to spam space while g9 is pressed

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

I have been attempting to create a while loop type thing to allow me to use a repeat macro while away from my pc with ghub as it does not allow repeat macros to be written to memory however lua scripts can be. The main issue i am having is that it infinitely repeats even when i release the button on my mouse.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9) then

local i=0

repeat

i = i+2

PressKey("spacebar")
Sleep(20)
ReleaseKey("spacebar")


until not event == ("MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9)


end

end
```

Comment: event an arg will never change, because that's just how variables work.

Comment: You don't need Lua script for this. You should make a looped macro and set its type "Toggle".

Comment: `it does not allow repeat macros to be written to memory` - what do you mean?

Comment: I want to use a macro written to the mouses memory and i want it to repeat while holding the button down this is not a feature that ghub supports and can only be done using a lua macro. Reason i want to have a the macro written to memory is because i will be using the mouse on an external device that can not download ghub and thus cant use the repeat function if written as a normal macro.

Comment: No. Lua macro cannot be stored in mouse memory and work without LGS/GHUB software running on your PC.

Comment: GHUB almost lacks support of programming mouse memory.  Try to uninstall GHUB, install LGS, and set mouse memory settings from there.

Comment: BTW, what is the external device? Is it some Linux box?   If it is Windows machine, then you can download LGS installer and install it off-line, so all Lua scripts will work.  Does LGS support your mouse?

Answer (score 0):

`OnEvent` will get called once per event. `Sleep` does **not** let it get called in the interim and even if it did `event` would not update. So you need another way to check if the state has updated. `IsMouseButtonPressed` should give you what you want so:

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 9 then
        repeat
            PressKey("spacebar")
            Sleep(20)
            ReleaseKey("spacebar")
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(9)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and useful explanation im not sure if its an issue with ghub or im being stupid but whenever i paste in your code i get hit with lua error 7 for an invalid argument in line 7.  Im not sure how to send images here so i will send a img link as to the output in ghub. https://imgur.com/a/iMQc0x6

Comment: `IsMouseButtonPressed` expects 1..5 as its argument.